# Default array parameters unexpectedly not empty

Tags: python, arrays, optional-parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

```
def stackdemo(stack=[]):
  stack.append('q')
  return stack

stackdemo()
print stackdemo()
```

returns `['q','q']`, whereas

```
stackdemo([])
print stackdemo([])
```

with the same function returns just `['q']`, as expected.

Why does Python appear to reuse  the array if the default is used? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

A list is a mutable object. From [doc](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values):

*The default value is evaluated only once. This makes a difference when the default is a mutable object such as a list, dictionary, or instances of most classes.*

Do it with `None`:

```
def stackdemo(stack=None):
    if stack is None:
        stack = []
    stack.append('q')
    return stack

stackdemo()
print stackdemo()
```

Comment: one-liner, clearer version of the `if` block: `stack = stack or []`

Comment: @JCotton - this is wrong. Imagine calling `stackdemo(l)` with `l = []` defined before (and used elsewhere).

Comment: you are right, though the one-liner may work in the OP's situation. It'd also be wrong with `stackdemo(mystr)` with `mystr=""` or other False values like that. It depends on the use and meaning of the `stack` variable. If a value of None has separate meaning or the variable could hold other valid-but-False values, then there is no substitute for the explicit `is None` check.

Answer (score 1):

In Python variables are passed by object reference, not by value.

This means that in this case you are modifying the `stack=[]` variable.

If you want to avoid this behaviour, than you have to generate the variable *within* the function since it will be generated on runtime in that case.

```
def stackdemo(stack=None):
    if stack is None:
        stack = []
    ...
```

Comment: The first line is not actually right. Read [this](http://effbot.org/zone/call-by-object.htm)

Comment: @JBernardo: it is correct but depends on your definition of value. Since I left out the "object" part it might be a bit unclear. I'll clarify it a bit :)